# Does Phaser framework know the orientation inside iframe?

Tags: iframe, phaser-framework

Can you anyone know how to detect orientation check in iframe for the Phaser framework?
Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Didn't found any solution, so i use this code on setResizeCallback:

```
if( window.orientation == 0 || screen.width < screen.height)
//portrait
else
//landscape
```